# In python, in what order would x = y == "true" evaluate

Tags: python, if-statement

I've come across instances where someone is assigning some variable x to another variable y, followed by == "true".

Do I set x to equal y if y equals "true"?

If it was just x = y = z, I would assume that both x and y are being set to the value of z. but a == outside of a conditional is throwing me

Comment: You're just assigning the result of a boolean expression to variable `x`

Comment: `y=="true"` is a True or False expression. `x = <expression>` is an assignment to `x`.

Comment: "but a == outside of a conditional is throwing me" it is quite normal... Did you try to actually run the code and see what happens?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is more obvious if you add parentheses according to operator precedence:

```
x = (y == "true")
```

`y == "true"` is an expression that evalutates to a `bool`, so it will be `True` or `False`. That value is then assigned to `x`.

Or in more words:

```
if y == "true":
    x = True
else:
    x = False
```

Answer (score 0):

`x = something` assigns the value "`something`" to `x`. `y == something` evaluates to `True` if the value of `y` is equal to "`something`", and evaluates to `False` if `y` is not equal to "`something`".

So, `x = y == "true"` means "set `x` to `True` if `y` is equal to the string `"true"`. Otherwise set `x` to `False`".